# rtf file format changes

Tags: ms-word, rtf, file-format

I want to know some interesting detail about Rich text format
Below is a sample of rich text format content opened in notepad

```
{\rtf1\mac\deff2 {\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss Chicago;}{\f2\froman New York;}{\f3\fswiss Geneva;}{\f4\fmodern Monaco;}{\f11\fnil Cairo;}{\f13\fnil Zapf Dingbats;}{\f16\fnil Palatino;}{\f18\fnil Zapf Chancery;}{\f20\froman Times;}{\f21\fswiss Helvetica;}
{\f22\fmodern Courier;}{\f23\ftech Symbol;}{\f24\fnil Mobile;}{\f100\fnil FoxFont;}{\f107\fnil MathMeteor;}{\f164\fnil Futura;}{\f1024\fnil American Heritage;}{\f2001\fnil Arial;}{\f2005\fnil Courier New;}{\f2010\fnil Times New Roman;}
{\f2011\fnil Wingdings;}{\f2515\fnil MT Extra;}{\f3409\fnil FoxPrint;}{\f11132\fnil InsigniaLQmono;}{\f11133\fnil InsigniaLQprop;}{\f14974\fnil LB Helvetica Black;}{\f14976\fnil L Helvetica Light;}}{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;\red0\green0\blue255;
\red0\green255\blue255;\red0\green255\blue0;\red255\green0\blue255;\red255\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;}{\stylesheet{\f4\fs18 \sbasedon222\snext0 Normal;}}{\info{\title samplepostscript.msw}{\author 
Computer Science Department}}\widowctrl\ftnbj \sectd \sbknone\linemod0\linex0\cols1\endnhere \pard\plain \qc \f4\fs18 {\plain \b\f21 Sample Rich Text Format Document\par 
}\pard {\plain \f20 \par 
}\pard \ri-80\sl-720\keep\keepn\absw570 {\caps\f20\fs92\dn6 T}{\plain \f20 \par 
}\pard \qj {\plain \f20 his is a sample rich text format (RTF), document. This document was created using Microsoft Word and then printing the document to a RTF file. It illustrates the very basic text formatting effects that can be achieved using RTF. 
\par 
\par 
}\pard \qj\li1440\ri1440\box\brdrs \shading1000 {\plain \f20 RTF }{\plain \b\f20 contains codes for producing advanced editing effects. Such as this indented, boxed, grayed background, entirely boldfaced paragraph.\par 
}\pard \qj {\plain \f20 \par 
Microsoft  Word developed RTF for document transportability and gives a user access to the complete set of the effects that can be achieved using RTF. \par 
}}
```

After editing this file in a MS word it gets changed a lot.I have not deleted or added any content to it by opening in MS word I deleted the word "illustrates " (which can be seen in above rtf file ) and then added the word again back in same position.  So nothing has changed in the file content.  But after saving the file, I opened it in text editor and so lot of changes

```
\par }\pard \ltrpar\ql \li0\ri-80\sl-720\slmult0\keep\keepn\widctlpar\absw570\wrapdefault\faauto\rin-80\lin0\itap0 {\rtlch\fcs1 \af46\afs92 \ltrch\fcs0 \caps\f46\fs92\dn6\insrsid1866410 \hich\af46\dbch\af31505\loch\f46 T}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af46\afs24 \ltrch\fcs0 
\f46\fs24\insrsid1866410 
\par }\pard \ltrpar\qj \li0\ri0\widctlpar\wrapdefault\faauto\rin0\lin0\itap0 {\rtlch\fcs1 \af46\afs24 \ltrch\fcs0 \f46\fs24\insrsid1866410 \hich\af46\dbch\af31505\loch\f46 
his is a sample rich text format (RTF), document. This document was created using Microsoft Word and then printing the document to a RTF file. It }{\rtlch\fcs1 \af46\afs24 \ltrch\fcs0 \f46\fs24\insrsid1866410 \hich\af46\dbch\af31505\loch\f46 illustrates }
{\rtlch\fcs1 \af46\afs24 \ltrch\fcs0 \f46\fs24\insrsid1866410 \hich\af46\dbch\af31505\loch\f46 the very basic text formatting effects that can be achieved using RTF. 
\par 
\par }\pard \ltrpar\qj \li1440\ri1440\widctlpar\brdrt\brdrs\brdrw15 \brdrl\brdrs\brdrw15 \brdrb\brdrs\brdrw15 \brdrr\brdrs\brdrw15 \wrapdefault\faauto\rin1440\lin1440\itap0 \shading1000 {\rtlch\fcs1 \af46\afs24 \ltrch\fcs0 \f46\fs24\insrsid1866410 
\hich\af46\dbch\af31505\loch\f46 RTF }{\rtlch\fcs1 \ab\af46\afs24 \ltrch\fcs0 \b\f46\fs24\insrsid1866410 \hich\af46\dbch\af31505\loch\f46 contains codes for pr\hich\af46\dbch\af31505\loch\f46 
oducing advanced editing effects. Such as this indented, boxed, grayed background, entirely boldfaced paragraph.
 \par }\pard \ltrpar\qj \li0\ri0\widctlpar\wrapdefault\faauto\rin0\lin0\itap0 {\rtlch\fcs1 \af46\afs24 \ltrch\fcs0 \f46\fs24\insrsid1866410
```

Main changes is that following line

```
}\pard \qj {\plain \f20 his is a sample rich text format (RTF), document. This document was created using Microsoft Word and then printing the document to a RTF file. It illustrates the very basic text formatting effects that can be achieved using RTF.
```

is replaced by

```
\par }\pard \ltrpar\qj \li0\ri0\widctlpar\wrapdefault\faauto\rin0\lin0\itap0 {\rtlch\fcs1 \af46\afs24 \ltrch\fcs0 \f46\fs24\insrsid1866410 \hich\af46\dbch\af31505\loch\f46 
his is a sample rich text format (RTF), document. This document was created using Microsoft Word and then printing the document to a RTF file. It }{\rtlch\fcs1 \af46\afs24 \ltrch\fcs0 \f46\fs24\insrsid1866410 \hich\af46\dbch\af31505\loch\f46 illustrates }
{\rtlch\fcs1 \af46\afs24 \ltrch\fcs0 \f46\fs24\insrsid1866410 \hich\af46\dbch\af31505\loch\f46 the very basic text formatting effects that can be achieved using RTF.
```

You can see the changes in the portion where I have cut and pasted the word "illustrates"to the file.  In that portion some things are added like

```
illustrates }
{\rtlch\fcs1 \af46\afs24 \ltrch\fcs0 \f46\fs24\insrsid1866410 \hich\af46\dbch\af31505\loch\f46 the very basic text formatting effects that can be achieved using RTF. "
```

So why does this changes occur?

**update:**
By below answer I found it is due to ms word adding some its own styles etc etc
Now my question is can i remove this appended source or code(for example {\rtlch\fcs1 \af46\afs24 \ltrch\fcs0 \f46\fs24\insrsid1866410 \hich\af46\dbch\af31505\loch\f46) from rtf file manually using binary tool? Does it make any error if I remove it? (for one file I did changes by deleting it manually, and when i checked content no data was deleted). But I want to know whether it is ok to delete it?

Answer (score 0):

It's partly because each version of Word has has introduced new features which have required new facilities within the RTF standard to represent them. In particular, the support provided in Word for different non-Unicode character encoding standards and for mixed scripts (LTR and LTR scrips and "East Asian" scripts) means that a lot of rtf code is concerned with encoding and text direction, even when you have a document that contains nothing except LTR text and Unicode encoding. (That's what all that ltrpar, hich, dbch, ltrch stuff is all about.

Many programs produce RTF and older code will typically produce RTF that corresponds to an older version of the standard. If you open such a document in a new version of Word and re-save as RTF, it will typically be saved using the new standard.

Comment: As i told in my question something {\rtlch\fcs1 \af46\afs24 \ltrch\fcs0 \f46\fs24\insrsid1866410 \hich\af46\dbch\af31505\loch\f46 is appended in between the sentence. Can i remove this appended things from the rtf? Does it make any error if i remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Today we got file with [broken encoding (screenshot done after repair)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdDlz.jpg)  and the best way to repair: looking for [specs](http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/rtfspec_7.html#rtfspec_21). The first thing u need to know is where to find strings — use rtf conftol words as *"\rtlch"* *"\ltrch"* or smthn like *"\loch\"* and *"\hich\"* parameters. In this case we've changed all of "**\loch\f616**" "**\hich\f616**" and other **fxxx** matches to **f0**.

***fN*** is Font number (***afN*** associated font numb). ***N*** refers to an entry in the font table. ***fsN*** or ***afsN*** means Font size.

For example:

This text looks like abrakadabra — 
**Àðáèòðàæíûé ñóä ãîðîäà Ìîñêâû**
Äåëî ¹ À40-63383/2018

We can find this string by using *ctrl+f* "**63383/2018**" and nowe we see in Sublime raw .rtf:

`{\rtlch\fcs1 \af793\afs24 \ltrch\fcs0 \b\f793\fs24\lang1033\langfe1033\langnp1033\insrsid7292261\charrsid9138747 \'c0\'f0\'e1\'e8\'f2\'f0
\'e0\'e6\'ed\'fb\'e9 \'f1\'f3\'e4 \'e3\'ee\'f0\'ee\'e4\'e0 \'cc\'ee\'f1\'ea\'e2\'fb}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs24 \ltrch\fcs0 \b\f0\fs24\lang1033\langfe1033\langnp1033\insrsid15809263\charrsid9138747 
\par }{\rtlch\fcs1 \af793\afs24 \ltrch\fcs0 \f793\fs24\lang1033\langfe1033\langnp1033\insrsid9842406\charrsid9138747 \'c4\'e5\'eb\'ee \'b9 \'c040-63383/2018}`

If we will change all ***"\af793"*** and ***"\f793"*** to ***"af0"*** and ***"f0"*** :

`{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs24 \ltrch\fcs0 \b\f0\fs24\lang1033\langfe1033\langnp1033\insrsid7292261\charrsid9138747 \'c0\'f0\'e1\'e8\'f2\'f0
\'e0\'e6\'ed\'fb\'e9 \'f1\'f3\'e4 \'e3\'ee\'f0\'ee\'e4\'e0 \'cc\'ee\'f1\'ea\'e2\'fb}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs24 \ltrch\fcs0 \b\f0\fs24\lang1033\langfe1033\langnp1033\insrsid15809263\charrsid9138747 
\par }{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs24 \ltrch\fcs0 \f0\fs24\lang1033\langfe1033\langnp1033\insrsid9842406\charrsid9138747 \'c4\'e5\'eb\'ee \'b9 \'c040-63383/2018}`

**Profit!** — **Арбитражный суд города Москвы**
Дело № А40-63383/2018

\b\ in front of chars means **bold** text, as u can see.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuxdj.jpg) you can see that other characters still has **"af739" and "f793"** and we cant read them in russian, but our example has af0 - so MS Word actually shows us right text.